# Rapid Application Developer - difference between "Publish" and "Republish"

Tags: java, websphere, ibm-rad

I am new to working with RAD for Websphere. After making some Java code changes I notice the server and the EAR deployed on it will say something like "Started, Publish". Today I started my server and it says "Started, Republish" (on both the server and EAR). Can someone give me a simple explanation of what is meant by "Publish", "Republish", and any other status(es) I may come across while working on a Java web app with RAD for Websphere? Also, what is the appropriate action to take for each status if I want my Java changes to be picked up? I tried bouncing the server without doing a new build and it doesnt appear to have made any difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Started` is the state in which your server starts deploying applications.

`Publish` is the state in which your server publishes a new application that was not already deployed. So, new deployment is `Publish`

`Republish` is the state in which your server already has published the application but there are few changes which need publishing again. So, instead of `Publish` since application is already deployed, server `Republish` the application to make sure that changes are published as well.

Comment: So then what is the difference between Publish and Synchronized?